# XSSFRichTextString with mixed font ignores newline after bold font only

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssf

In below code, I intend to have "Jack Reacher" in bold style and the rest of the string as normal font. I am not able to see the newline appended in report after "Jack Reacher". Newline gets applied if I comment and ignore bold `descEntryRichStr.applyFont(0, name.length() , boldedFont);`

I have added `cs.setWrapText(true);` also but it still doesnt work

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Test First");

    XSSFFont boldedFont = workbook.createFont();
    boldedFont.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);

    String newLine  = "\n";
    String name = "Jack Reacher";
    String fileNo = "Professsion : Doctor";
    String other = "Address : New-york" ;

    String finalString = name +newLine + fileNo + newLine + other;

    Row row = sheet.createRow(0); 
    XSSFCell cell = (XSSFCell) row.createCell(0);

    CreationHelper creationHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();

    XSSFRichTextString descEntryRichStr = (XSSFRichTextString) creationHelper.createRichTextString(finalString);
    descEntryRichStr.applyFont(0, name.length() , boldedFont);
    cell.setCellValue(descEntryRichStr);
    XSSFCellStyle cs = cell.getCellStyle();
    cs.setWrapText(true);
    cell.setCellStyle(cs);

    System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());

    try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("/shared/sample/report-"+new Date().getTime() +".xlsx")) {
        workbook.write(outputStream);
    }
```

[Here is the snippet of report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwEyo.jpg)

Comment: Already applied the solution as suggested. But it still doesnt work. Here in my case , the issue is due to applying separate fonts in the cell string

Comment: Voted to reopen. The linked answer states that `setWrapText(true)` must be used. But this is exactly what @riyaj sande already does. The problem is that he does this in the default cell style. Either he should creating a new cell style or, better, he should use `org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellUtil` to set cell style property:  `org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellUtil.setCellStyleProperty(cell, org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellUtil.WRAP_TEXT, true);`

Comment: @Gagravarr: How is this a duplicate of the answer you linked? The linked answer states that setWrapText(true) must be used. But this is exactly what riyaj sande already does.

Comment: Thank you @ Axel Richter for the solution. I was using old 3.6 dependency version. The code works in case dependency is 3.9 or more, with using either setWrapText(true) OR CellUtil.setCellStyleProperty()